# Unity Licensing Server allows to lease only one license of two

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have two Unity Pro Build Server seats. Both licenses are served by a single Unity Licensing Server.

The latest imported license file contains this text:

```
<LicenseGroup LicenseCount="2" ...
```

So assume it lists two licenses.

But the Licensing Server still does not allow to lease two licenses at a time. I mean two concurrent builds in TeamCity.

Why?

Comment: thats one to ask on your priority support. It allows 2 licenses to the same project,  id never have assumed concurrent builds.. Just like id never assume you buy an asset on one the other gets it, it doesnt mean you get 2..

Comment: @BugFinder these are Build Server floating licenses, you need two if you want two concurrent builds :)) If you do serial builds only then you can have only one license obviously.